# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null even after body load

Tags: javascript, html

I have browsed this site for my problem already, now I found a lot of threads about it but none helped me out.
I created a JSFiddle with my code to make it easier for you all to see 
I tried putting my  tag just before my closing  tag and even after my closing  tag but still tget the same error specified in the title
here is the location of the script tag and part of my script:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/scripts/dynamicpage.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

(this is the end of the html file)

```
 function loadHome()
{
    var titleID = document.getElementById(main_title);
    var homepage = "Dit is de home-page";
    var imgID = document.getElementById(side_img1);
    var text_container = document.getElementById(main_text);
    titleID.innerHTML = "Welkom op de site voor echte stroopwafel liefhebbers!";
    text_container.innerHTML = homepage;
    imgID.src="http://informatica-cals.nl/jboekhout/resources/home.jpg";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m0jx7v2d/

Comment: Something completely unrelated, but still - you shouldn't use Allman-style braces in Javascript as it may lead to hard-to-spot errors (see http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/)

Answer (score 3):

Use string instead of variables. Notice the double quotes.

```
var titleID = document.getElementById("main_title");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
var titleID = document.getElementById(main_title);
```

it should be:

```
var titleID = document.getElementById("main_title");
```

Take a look at [HTML DOM getElementById() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) for more information.